# Replace Arabic comma with English in a string Java

Tags: java, string, replace, arabic

I am trying to replace Arabic number characters to English for this I am replacing any instance of Arabic character using below method, but the only problem is that I am unable to convert Arabic comma to English comma using particular method.

```
 public String convertNumbersToEnglish(String str) {
        if(str!=null && !str.equals("")){
            String answer = str;
            answer = answer.replace("١", "1");
            answer = answer.replace("٢", "2");
            answer = answer.replace("٣", "3");
            answer = answer.replace("٤", "4");
            answer = answer.replace("٥", "5");
            answer = answer.replace("٦", "6");
            answer = answer.replace("٧", "7");
            answer = answer.replace("٨", "8");
            answer = answer.replace("٩", "9");
            answer = answer.replace("٠", "0");
            answer = answer.replace("،",",");
            return answer;
        }else{
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you got an example of a String with an Arabic comma in, that fails to be replaced by your code?

Comment: yes i did try it but the comma is inverted

Comment: Then you'll need to include a `replace` command for _that_ type of comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if you are in android

```
answer = answer.replace("\\u060C",",");
```

Comment: I don't believe this will do anything that the original code doesn't already do.  The character in OP's final `replace` call is precisely `\u060C`.

Comment: I have tested it in my android device it worked but specifying the above method didn't work as expected

Comment: yes it worked thaks I was also testing it in my andorid application when language changes to arabic the comma was not replaced however other letters replacement was working fine.

Comment: @FaisalNaseer This is why I asked OP to supply an example with an Arabic comma that fails to be replaced by his code.  If he can supply such a String, it'll be something with an unusual type of comma - not `\u060C`.  In that case, you'll find that your code also won't replace the comma.